# Two concatenated templates with each a concept-constraint

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename K>
    requires is_nothrow_move_constructible<K>::value
struct S
{
    using value_type = pair<K, K>;
    struct iterator
    {
    };
    template<typename P>
        requires is_constructible<value_type, P &&>::value
    pair<iterator, bool> insert( P &&x );
};

template<typename K>
    requires is_nothrow_move_constructible<K>::value
template<typename P>
    requires is_constructible<typename S<K>::value_type, P &&>::value
pair<typename S<K>::iterator, bool> S<K>::insert( P &&x )
{
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Why does this compile with g++ 11.1.0 and not with clang 12.0.0. The clang-error is:

```
xxx.cpp:24:43: error: out-of-line definition of 'insert' does not match any declaration in 'S<K>'
pair<typename S<K>::iterator, bool> S<K>::insert( P &&x )
                                          ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

clang++ 13.0.0 under Windows does report the same error.

MSVC 19.29.30136 gives the following error:

```
xxx.cpp
xxx.cpp(25): error C2244: 'S<K>::insert': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
xxx.cpp(24): note: see declaration of 'S<K>::insert'
xxx.cpp(25): note: definition
xxx.cpp(25): note: 'std::pair<S<K>::iterator,bool> S<K>::insert(P &&)'
xxx.cpp(25): note: existing declarations
xxx.cpp(25): note: 'std::pair<S<K>::iterator,bool> S<K>::insert(P &&)'
```

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

When you have a definition of a function template that is separate from the declaration, the two have to match *exactly* - be token for token identical (modulo parameter names). In your case, they don't match - you have `value_type` in one case and `typename S<K>::value_type` in the other, so this is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The easy workaround is: just define the function in-line so you don't have even have to worry about copying the declaration. This definitely works, and is almost always clearer anyway.

If you really want out-of-line definitions, then you need to restructure your declaration so that it allows you to name `value_type` the same way in both cases:

```cpp
template<typename K>
    requires is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<K>
struct S
{
    using value_type = pair<K, K>;
    struct iterator
    { };

    template<typename P>
    auto insert( P &&x ) -> pair<iterator, bool>
        requires is_constructible_v<value_type, P &&>;
};

template<typename K>
    requires is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<K>
template<typename P>
auto S<K>::insert( P &&x ) -> pair<iterator, bool>
    requires is_constructible_v<value_type, P &&>
{
}
```

On the several advantages of the *trailing-return-type* approach to writing functions is that the class itself is in scope when you're doing name lookup in the contexts after it appears. So in the definition above, `iterator` and `value_type` are looked up in `S<K>`, which allows you to use the same token sequence (and also just lets you avoid repeating them for no reason).

---

Also, I changed your traits to use the form `meow_v<T>` instead `meow<T>::value`, since that's shorter.

Comment: I don't believe you're right because g++ does compile the code ! But thanks for the workaround. If you would be right the following wouldn't compile: "struct S { struct T { }; T x(); }; typename S::T S::x() { }". But it compiles with any compiler. And you dropped the concept for P. If I drop the P-constraint everything compiles fine.

Comment: @Bonita That's not a template and has no constraints that need to be identical?